# How to export executed statements from Oracle SQLDeveloper?

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

There is a statements logging in Oracle SQLDeveloper:

[image: statements log]

Is there any way to export them as plain text or log them to file?

**UPD**: The reason I want to collect statements to file is for easy diff (to compare expected vs truncated export). I have a schema which export is not completely performed by 'Tools -> Database export'. Indexes, constraints, packages and synonyms are missing in resulting file while they are obviously present in database and visible in SQLDeveloper.

Comment: so your real question is why your Database Export isn't 'working' - we can help with that as well with more details...the database object type selectors work a very particular way, it's most likely you 'got what you asked for' but maybe didn't realize that's what you were asking for

Comment: I have a copy of database export from June and it was complete. Now in November I do export again with the same set of parameters: Pretty print, show schema, grant, terminator, add FORCE to views, without exporting data and with 'Proceed to summary' checkbox. The export is truncated. I have the same schema on Test environment and with the same SQLDeveloper, resulting schema dump is complete 

Comment: i totally believe you, but please start a new question with the details, and we'll talk about it over there

Answer (score 2):

No, just copy and paste.

You could always do a client based jdbc trace or a database session trace if you wanted that to go to a file.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. There is too much for copy and paste. I would like to analyse statements created by 'Tools -> Database Export'. What do you mean by 'client based jdbc trace'? Would be nice to find a configuration parameter to redirect statements to a file

Comment: What are you looking to accomplish, end of day? The log here is for debugging/investigating how the tool works...

Comment: sql developer is a java application using an Oracle JDBC driver...so you have all of those tools. like i said, you could also just use a session trace on the database side...or use the filter in the log panel to narrow down to what you want to look at

Comment: ctrl-A, ctrl-C, ctrl-V - that picks up everything, not sure what you mean, it's 'too much to copy and paste' - if you send it to a file, it'll be the same amount of information there

Comment: As said in the title: I am looking for a way to export it to a file, because this way it will be easier for me to inspect. Thanks! Ctrl-A, Ctrl-C works, earlier I tried to use Cmd-A, Cmd-C since I am on Mac and it did not work. You can add hotkeys method to your answer.